# How to install sp server 2013 on win8.1 pro

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

My laptop is running with win 8 pro.

How can i install SP server 2013 on my laptop?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If you want it "close to the metal" without installing a server OS,
>   you can now decide for yourself if it is a good idea. It is COMPLETELY
>   unsupported by MS and should only be used for a local development/demo
>   machine.
>
> ​First, download SharePoint foundation 2013 with SP1​ or SharePoint
>   Server 2013 with SP1. If you need to apply a language pack, you can
>   get them here. This setup requires you to be joined to a domain. You
>   can also use local accounts.

Source: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx

Comment: i run pre- installation file and get error:
Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configuration error
. I can not add role in win 8 pro server manager

Comment: @NguyenAnhDuc, I am not sure about it as I haven't done it myself.

Comment: Please read the attached blog article.